# Controller not match with url

Tags: java, struts2, tomcat7

i have a problem loading a page. I defined in the struts.xml (located in Java Resources/src/com.infopool.action) the next configuration:

```
<struts>
    <package name="demo" namespace="/demo" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="Inicio" class="com.infopool.action.Demo">
            <result name="success">/View/demo/start.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="Hola" class="com.infopool.action.Demo" method="hello">
            <result name="success">/View/demo/hello.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="Chau" class="com.infopool.action.Demo" method="goodbye">
            <result name="success">/View/demo/goodbye.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

So, in the package com.infopool.action i have the next class defined:

```
package com.infopool.action;

    public class Demo {

        public String execute(){
            return "success";
        }

        public String hello(){
            return "success";
        }

        public String goodbye(){
            return "success";
        }

    }
```

The views are located into WebContent/View/demo. When i try to browse the page, an 404 Tomcat error appear. The URL is:

`http://localhost:8080/Infopool/demo/Inicio.action`

My web.xml have the next configuration:

```
  <filter>
    <filter-name>Main</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>actionPackages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.infopool.action</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Main</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

What is wrong with my configuration ?.

Comment: do you see any error while running your webapp ?

Comment: `<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />` put it after your `<struts>`. this will enable the devMode for you to see some useful log messages

Comment: In the console not appears errors. I update the post with the web.xml config.

Comment: try to remove your `<init-param>
        <param-name>actionPackages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.infopool.action</param-value>
    </init-param>`. just a hunch tho

Comment: thanks for providing your web.xml, because i dont see any problem with your struts configuration.

Comment: im looking forward to see the outcome.

Answer (score 1):

the use of this one is to pass an action package where all the action classes has been declared

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>actionPackages</param-name>
    <param-value>com.infopool.action</param-value>
</init-param>
```

but your Demo action class doesnt have any annotation configuration like (if im not mistaken.)

```
@Namespace("/demo")
@Action("/Inicio")
@ResultPath(value="/")
@Result(name="success",location="/View/demo/start.jsp")
public class Demo {
....
```

You used the other way on configuring your action class which is your struts.xml

```
<struts>
    <package name="demo" namespace="/demo" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="Inicio" class="com.infopool.action.Demo">
            <result name="success">/View/demo/start.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="Hola" class="com.infopool.action.Demo" method="hello">
            <result name="success">/View/demo/hello.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="Chau" class="com.infopool.action.Demo" method="goodbye">
            <result name="success">/View/demo/goodbye.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

so no need to declare/create this,

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>actionPackages</param-name>
    <param-value>com.infopool.action</param-value>
</init-param>
```

inside of your struts filter.

[#1 look at this : Providing an init-parameter in struts filter](http://www.concretepage.com/struts-2/struts-2-strutsprepareandexecutefilter-web-xml)

[#2 see this sample : struts2 annotation](http://www.concretepage.com/struts-2/struts-2-annotation-simple-login-example)

Comment: Also, No need to declare a second too.

Comment: hi sir glad to hear your thoughts  what do you mean by `second` ? :)

Comment: I mean annotation configuration. It's not provided by XWork, thus not the basic configuration. Also it isn't used by OP.

Comment: ahh gets.  about that i just mention it for clarification not suggesting to use it btw :)

Comment: For what clarification? It won't work because 1) it's wrong configured 2) convention-plugin is required, 3) xml configuration has a priority, so your configuration is never used.

Comment: hello sir :) can you explain what is your understanding about my answer .

Comment: nothing but two links not related to OP's problem. You should know that link-only answers are prohibited on SO.

Comment: now i get it. you are referring to those two links. link #1 related to `<init-param>` 's OP declaration how it works. then the link #2 is just a proof gonna edit now sorry

Comment: btw sir why dont post your own answer ? i think you have an idea it may help the OP . just want to help, shared what i had understand on OP question and if the op not satisfied with my answer he can ignore it.